# Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel

Tags: android

I was trying out a simple program (with editbox and a button) to understand the MVVM and databinding feature in Android. I am getting an error, when I added the  field in the activity_main.xml. 
I have renamed the package and the class names, but is getting the error "Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel".

I have updated the code below. Please help in understanding the cause of the error.

**UPDATED**

> MainActivity :

```
package com.example.newmvvm.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel;
import com.example.newmvvm.R;
import com.example.newmvvm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMainBinding.setViewModel(new listViewModel());
        listViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(listViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

> listViewModel:

```
package com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel;

import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.example.newmvvm.Model.DB;

public class listViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    DB db;

    public listViewModel(){
        db = new db("");
    }

    public String setTextMsg(String text){
        db.setTextMsgModel(text);
    }
    public String getTextMsg(){
        return db.getTextMsgModel();
    }
    public void onClick(){
        //TODO
    }

}
```

DB :

```
package com.example.newmvvm.Model;

public class DB {
    private String textMsgModel;
    public DB(String text){
        this.textMsgModel = text;
    }
    public String setTextMsgModel(String text){
        this.textMsgModel = text;
    }
    public String getTextMsgModel(){
        return this.textMsgModel;
    }
    public void onClickModel(){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".View.MainActivity">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel" />
    </data>

<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{ViewModel.setTextMsg}"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="21dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

> gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newmvvm"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

> Run Log :

```
9:09:36 PM: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build] in project 
C:\Users\rbeat\AndroidStudioProjects\NewMVVM\app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> couldn't make a guess for com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
9:09:38 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

Comment: type="com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel" is the cause of the error. But I feel the directory name and the class name are provided appropriately.

Comment: listViewModel java class extends the ViewModel and is part of the folder ListViewModel under com.example.newmvvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here `com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel`.

I guess this your package name`ListViewModel` and it contain this class `listViewModel`.

In `databinding`  package name should in lowercase and `class` name should start with Uppercase .if it not it will won't find.

Rename this package name `ListViewModel` with this `listviewmodel`.

And rename your `listViewModel`  Observable class with this `ListViewModel`.

Your type look like this.

```
type="com.example.newmvvm.listViewModel.ListViewModel"
```

Add also remove this line .`listViewModel` is not `viewmodel` it is `Observable` class.

```
listViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(listViewModel.class);
```

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> couldn't make a guess for com.example.newmvvm.listviewmodel.listViewModel

Comment: I renamed the class name to ListViewModel - all caps. It compiled.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not generating data binding object for your layout i.e

```
MainActivityBinding binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.main_activity);
```

Now set data binding using viewmodel In activity

```
Yourviewmodelclass  viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(yourviewmodelclass.class);

binding.SetviewModel(viewModel)
```

And your not setting view model

Comment: Thanks.I have updated the code above and I am still with the same error.

Comment: Your viewmodel class need to extends ViewModel.

Comment: Changed to "public class listViewModel extends ViewModel,BaseObservable {" , still the same error

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMainBinding.setViewModel(new listViewModel());
        listViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(listViewModel.class);
    }

Comment: Remove baseObseravle class from extend

Comment: Extend only viewmodel class

Comment: Its still the same, after removing the BaseObservable class

Comment: Did u enable the databinding in Gradle file?

Comment: In your current activity code u are not initializing view model class

Comment: Your are not initializing view model

Comment: Add this in activity code     Yourviewmodelclass viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(yourviewmodelclass.class);

Comment: I have edited my question with the modifications I added through. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205404/discussion-between-angus-and-hasan-hasan).